# Laravel relationship through an array of JSON objects

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, eloquent

**Models:**

> **User** which *hasMany* **groups**, and *hasMany* **roles** *through* **group**

and

> **Group** which *hasMany* **users**.

These relationships are being stored on the **group** table, in a column called 'members', which is formatted as follows:

```
[
    {
        user_id: *user_id_one*
        role_id: *role_id_one*
    },
    {
        user_id: *user_id_two*
        role_id: *role_id_two*
    },
]
```

---

**Requirements:**

- The models must be linked through a relationship, so that I can eagerly load them.
- I cannot change the data structure because a very large amount of programming has already been done regarding these models and structures.
- It must be done using sql version from 5.7
- It must be done using php 7.1, 7.2, or 7.3

---

**That I've tried:**

I first tried this in the **User** model:

```
method:
$this->hasMany('\App\Group', 'members->[*].user_id')

query:
select * from `groups` where json_unquote(json_extract(`groups`.`members`, '$."[*].user_id"')) = ? and json_unquote(json_extract(`groups`.`members`, '$."[*].user_id"')) is not null
```

Then:

```
method:
$this->hasMany('\App\Group', 'members->[*].user_id')
or
$this->hasMany('\App\Group', 'members->$[*].user_id')

query:
Column Not Found
```

The mighty *staudenmeir/eloquent-json-relations* got me closer with

```
method:
$this->hasManyJson('\App\Group', 'members->[*].user_id')

query:
select * from `groups` where json_contains(`groups`.`members`, ?, '$."[*].user_id"')
```

---

These were all tried with the normal primary key and custom attributes which returned:

- "JSON_ARRAY(*primary_key*)"
- "JSON_OBJECT('id',*primary_key*)"
- "['*primary_key*']"
- "{'id': '*primary_key*'}"

However these all were escaped with quotes.

---

**Already Considered:**

Here is an example of a working attribute

```
public function getGroupsAttribute()
{
    return Group::whereRaw("JSON_CONTAINS(members->'$[*].user_id', JSON_ARRAY('{$this->id}'))")->get();
}
```

---

I figured before I went off and made a custom relationship I would ask here. I could probably do something with a scope to apply something like the following (with a relationship that just returned all groups) but it would be the same amount of work and less clean.

```
->with(['groups' => function ($query) use ($user) {
   $query->whereRaw("JSON_CONTAINS(members->'$[*].user_id', JSON_ARRAY('{$user->id}'))")
}])
```

Comment: I changed the values of a psuedo-randomly selected members column, for demonstration purposes. Assume the column is valid JSON.

Comment: *"I cannot change the data structure..."* cue the meme of [David Tennant in the rain](https://gph.is/1IM4cKr), saying "I'm sorry. I'm so, so sorry."

Comment: The example of a foreign key reference based on a JSON field is a major part of my presentation [How to Use JSON in MySQL Wrong](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-use-json-in-mysql-wrong).

Comment: @BillKarwin Ik man, if it were up to me I would just have made a pivot table (ノ﹏ヽ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `eloquent-json-relations` package, you can implement a `groups` relationship like this:

```
class User extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentJsonRelations\HasJsonRelationships;

    public function groups()
    {
       return $this->hasManyJson(Group::class, 'members[]->user_id');
    }
}

class Group extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentJsonRelations\HasJsonRelationships;
}
```